# There is something wrong with backslash ("\") behaviour in comments

Tags: support, bug, comments, markdown

I was writing comment [to the question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1093066/66509)(about Samba, so it uses UNC with backslashes).

The source code of my comment:

```
On Linux you should use `//` instead of `\\`. On Windows you should use only `\\`. My idea was to determine full share name from Nautilus - for example `smb://host_name_or_ip/share_name` to write then it as `\\host_name_or_ip/share_name` on device.
```

Here (in question/answer fields) it renders normally as:

> On Linux you should use `//` instead of `\\`. On Windows you should use only `\\`. My idea was to determine full share name from Nautilus - for example `smb://host_name_or_ip/share_name` to write then it as `\\host_name_or_ip/share_name` on device.

But in comments it is rendered incorrectly:

> [image: Wrong rendering in comment]

I see that problematic parts contain backslash ("\").
Is it a bug in comments renderer?

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember the details, but there are differences in how markdown works in posts, in comments and in chat. In your case, you want this (see the comment under my answer for a demonstration):

```
you should use `//` instead of ``\\`` foo.
```

I am guessing the issue is some combination of i) having many backticks and ii) having one of the backticks escaped (`` \` ``). Anyway, using double backticks around the `\\` works.

Comment: ```you should use `//` instead of ``\\`` foo.``` renders as: you should use `//` instead of ``\\`` foo.